# RCP: JxBrowser license check failed: No valid license found

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp, jxbrowser

Today I started experimenting with JxBrowser. Starting the [sample](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013072-using-jxbrowser-in-swt) with the public static main worked as expected (and it could find the license.jar).

I added a button to a view to start the sample:

```
btnStart.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                new JxBrowserJavaFXSWT();
            }
        });
```

Now I'm receiving:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JxBrowser license check failed: No valid license found.
```

Which is actually odd because it's added the classpath. I tried adding a new Plugin-Project (which is loaded fine) and add the license.jar to its classpath: not working.
I tried to add it to the manifest.mf, build.properties

manifest.mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: License
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.teamdev.jxbrowser.license
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.teamdev.jxbrowser.license.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: TEAMDEV
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

build.properties

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               license.jar
src.includes = license.jar
jars.extra.classpath = license.jar
```

Question: is there a way to add the license.jar to my rcp project and/or what am I missing?

P.S.: if informations are missing to help me solve this I'll gladly add more code, etc

Comment: I had started a discussion in the JxBrowser Forum: https://groups.google.com/a/teamdev.com/forum/#!topic/jxbrowser-forum/cK2OxyBhF2g, but like greg-449 stated I just added it to the Bundle-ClassPath and it worked.

Comment: Thank you flavio for your answer. I copied the devteam.licences to my META-INF folder and it doesn't work (not finding the licence)

Answer (score 2):

I received the same error, and I have a solution.

Just create a new mail ID and send a request to get a license of JX Browser using that new account, and get it and Download.

Then add that license.jar file in your project. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the license.jar in the main plugin class path - the 'Bundle-Classpath'.

Open the MANIFEST.MF editor, switch to the Runtime tab and add the license.jar to the Classpath section (you should also still have the . entry). The Bundle-Classpath should end up looking like:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 library.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I added it to the classpath section: didn't work
I then added it to Build > Runtime Information: didn't work
I pressed Overview > Update the classpath settings: no effect

Edit 2:
Main plugin manifest.mf contains Bundle-ClassPath: license.jar,
 .

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a perfect answer but I can give you a hint.

First you can extract the `licence.jar` file to change the extension from `.jar` to `.zip`.

Then you can see the following file:

```
Product: JxBrowser
Version: 6.x
Licensed to: 
License type: Evaluation
License info: Single-user license
Expiration date: 22-03-2099
Support expiration date: 22-03-2099
Generation date: 20-02-2017
Platforms: mac/x64;win32/x64;linux/x64;mac/x86;linux/x86;win32/x86;mac/ppc
Company name: NO COMPANY

SigB: jpg317l89241ihodylpum17e2gnk1ufx7bsql1dboldc25pp941s7ksw0wph
SigA: mdluetwphf1vcbl2yzs3ks5c4417pexopgnmap146g8ggk4r4e9ucrzmf1xo
```

You have to change the values of `SigB` and `SigA`.

I tried it, after changing `date`, but it does not work.